# Double click required sometimes, but not always

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, jsx

I'm currently building a little React app, backed by Redux and Firebase. One of the features I've added is to toggle/save likes for user profiles. If something is already liked, it only takes a single click to un-like and another single click to re-like. However, on a new load, to like something for the first time it requires a double click, then each following event takes a single click to like/un-like.

At first I thought the `e.preventDefault()` was messing with things, but I removed it and the problem continued. The I blamed it on `Link`, but I switched that to a plain `div` and still had the same issue.

How can I get rid of that double click to like something for the first time?

## Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { saveFavorite } from "../redux/actions";

class VenueSummary extends Component {
    state = {
        loved: false
    };

    toggleHeart = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.saveFavorite(this.props.venue, this.state.loved);
        this.setState({ loved: !this.state.loved });
    };

    render() {
        const { venue, loved, name } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="card-title">
                {name}
                <i
                className={loved ? "fas fa-heart right" : "far fa-heart right"}
                onClick={this.toggleHeart}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        saveFavorite: (venue, loved) => dispatch(saveFavorite(venue, loved))
    };
};

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(VenueSummary);
```

### Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import VenueSummary from "./VenueSummary";

const VenueList = props => {
    const { favorites, venues } = props;

    const venueList =
        venues && favorites ? (
        venues.map(venue => {
            const loved = favorites.includes(venue.id);
            return (
            <Link to={"/venue/" + venue.id} key={venue.id} className="col s6">
                <VenueSummary venue={venue} loved={loved} />
            </Link>
            );
        })
        ) : (
        <p>No venues to show</p>
        );
    return <div className="venue-list section">{venueList}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const favorites = state.firebase.profile.favorites;
    return { favorites };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
)(VenueList);
```

## Redux Action

```
export const saveFavorite = (venue, loved) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const userId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const venueId = venue.id;
        const user = firestore.collection("users").doc(userId);

        if (loved) {
            user.update({
                favorites: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(venueId)
            });
        } else {
            user.update({
                favorites: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(venueId)
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing local component `state` with state from the `redux` store in your `VenueSummary` for the `loved` prop. You should use only one or the other, in this case the redux value for `loved`. I would recommend removing `loved` from `state` entirely and do:

```
    toggleHeart = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {loved} = this.props;
        // toggle loved through redux
        this.props.saveFavorite(this.props.venue, !loved);
    };
```

The issue you describe arises for a couple of reasons - one is that the initial value of `loved` in state is not being synchronized to the value from `props` - if `props.loved` is already `true`, `state.loved` still starts as `false`. Another is that your current `toggleHeart` function has an error where you are not negating the value of `this.state.loved` when passing it to the redux action. You would need to solve both of those issues if for some reason you wanted to track `loved` in `this.state`.